# Custom control and element binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm creating custom control which will contain grid with dynamically added (or removed) rows and columns. Each cell has to contain checkbox which will be binded with some model. If user clicks on checkbox, the dictionary should refresh.

`Model.cs`

```
public class Model
{
    public Model(List<PanelModel> panels)
    {
        this.Panels = new Dictionary<int, bool>();   
        panels.ForEach(panel => this.Panels.Add(panel.Id, false));
    }

    ...

    public Dictionary<int, bool> Panels { get; set; } 
}
```

`CustomControl.cs`

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox
{
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
};
Grid.SetRow(checkBox, index);
Grid.SetColumn(checkBox, innerIndex);

Binding binding = new Binding(string.Format("Panels[{0}]", panel.Id));
binding.Source = this.Configurations;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
checkBox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);

this.mainGrid.Children.Add(checkBox);
```

How can I bind specific checkbox with element in dictionary `Panels`? Dictionary contains `int` - `bool` pair which means, that panel with ID x  is on or off.

Now, if I click on checkbox, nothing happenes. Debugger shows, that all panels are false (off).

Comment: Are your sure that `this.Configurations` is really of type `Model`? That isn't obvious from your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I would approach this with an ItemsControl where the ItemsSource is bound to your collection.

Then add an ItemTemplate that presents the bool via a binding to a checkbox.

You can set the ItemsControl PanelTemplate to a WrapPanel to still get the grid layout look.

Comment: The problem is, that I render all columns and rows dynamically, depend on two another collections.

Comment: What does your column and row collection contain?

Comment: Rows is collection of panels, and columns are configurations. They are mixed. I think it too much complicated to explain and I figured it out in event driven approach.